# JSON marshal returns incorrect utf8 Baht currency character ฿

Tags: go, utf-8

I have a Go API which marshals a baht symbol ฿ as "à¸¿". The string is stored correctly in MySQL 8. The string is consumed by a Flutter application and I can see by the response body that the currently symbol is already corrupted on arrival so the problem seems to lie with Go. This used to work but has recently broken.

my DB column

```
currency VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '$',

mysql> select currency from venues;
+----------+
| currency |
+----------+
| ฿        |
| ฿        |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

my Go code

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func (rs *appResource) venue(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    start := time.Now()

    userID := getUserFromJWT(r)

    log.Println(userID)

    user, err := getUser(rs.db, int64(userID))

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("user not found")
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    venue, err := getVenue(rs.db, user.VenueID)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("venue not found")
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    venueJSON, err := json.Marshal(venue)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    httpDuration := time.Since(start)
    requestDuration.WithLabelValues("GET /venue").Observe(httpDuration.Seconds())
    requestsProcessed.Inc()

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(venueJSON))
}

func getVenue(db *sql.DB, venueID int64) (Venue, error) {
    var venue Venue

    sqlStatement := "SELECT id, name, currency FROM venues WHERE active=1 AND id=?"

    row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, venueID)

    err := row.Scan(&venue.VenueID, &venue.Name, &venue.Currency)

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        fmt.Println("venue not found")
        return venue, nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return venue, err
    }

    return venue, err
}
```

model

```
type Venue struct {
    VenueID     int64  `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Currency    string `json:"currency"`
}
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or at the very least, the code that reads from the DB, whatever processing is done, and debug output at various stages.

Comment: this play ground is correct, please show us your code. see playground code: https://play.golang.org/p/Fil7-zkMxnc

Comment: edited to show  more complete code.

Comment: How about some debug statements? Probably after the DB scan and before/after the json marshaling.

Comment: The likelihood that Go messed up with UTF-8 is practically zero. The most efficient way of debugging this is to look elsewhere for an error. Note that MySQL is know to be a bit special about full Unicode.

Comment: You're right, a curl is giving me the correct answer to it's Flutter not displaying the character correctly

Comment: consider using its encoded version https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/thai-currency-symbol-baht/

Comment: The problem seems to be MySQL in Docker. The same database encoding on localhost and withing Docker return different results for the character, CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci.